# repaint and setColor in AWT

Tags: java, awt

Why does the `setColor` of a `Graphics` object reset when I use the `repaint` method?

Comment: Could we see a litle code please?  Having some more context helps answer questions.

Answer (score 2):

[seen here](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html)

> When AWT invokes this method, the Graphics object parameter is pre-configured with the appropriate state for drawing on this particular component: 
>   The Graphics object's color is set to the component's foreground property. 
>   The Graphics object's font is set to the component's font property.
>  
>   The Graphics object's translation is set such that the coordinate (0,0) represents the upper left corner of the component. 
>   The Graphics object's clip rectangle is set to the area of the component that is in need of repainting.

That's means your Graphics object is always reset to your component property each time that the paint / repaint method is called.  To keep your Color  (setColor) you should setColor on your component instead of on your Graphics object.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are overriding `paint(Graphics)` (or possibly `update`), and not always setting the colour in there. `Component` sets the colour (and font) of the `Graphics` object from its own settings. The `Graphics` object you receive is unlikely to be the same one from one paint to another.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you draw an image. If so: after drawing your image the color sets default back to `Color.BLACK`